# Push an Array forward so it will start from 150?

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, zedgraph

I have this function which is SMA (Simple Moving Average). The result in the array I display as graph in ZedGraph and now it will start from 0 to 1956. I want the graph to start from frameSize / 2 in this case example it will be 300 / 2 so 150 so the graph should start from 150 to 2016.

I don't want to make the graph to grow I mean the array should stay length as 1956 I just want it to be pushed by 150 indexes from the beginning so it will start from index 150 instead of 0.

So this is the SMA function:

```
private static double[] smaDoubles(int frameSize, int[] data)
{
    int padding = frameSize / 2;
    double sum = 0;
    double[] avgPoints = new double[(padding + data.Length) - frameSize + 1];

    for (int counter = padding; counter <= data.Length - frameSize; counter++)
    {
        int innerLoopCounter = 0;
        int index = counter;
        while (innerLoopCounter < frameSize)
        {
            sum = sum + data[index];

            innerLoopCounter += 1;

            index += 1;

        }

        avgPoints[counter] = sum / frameSize;

        sum = 0;

    }

    return avgPoints;

}
```

In the for loop counter = padding before it was counter = 0 so the result of that is in the image [here](http://imageshack.us/f/266/tostack.jpg/).

The green one is the SMA from this function. And the green start from 150 but ends at 1956 and it should end at 2106. When I moved it to start from 150 I want the whole graph to move as one unit by 150 so it will start from 150 and end in 2106. The red graph should stay the same all

How can I do it?

Now as it is in the image the graph end by 300 from the right edge.

This is the function as it is now i changed the line: double[] avgPoints = new double[data.Length - frameSize + 1]; this is how it was original so i changed it to this one now.
And the function get frameSize as 3 and data as [10] and im getting the same exception:

```
private static double[] smaDoubles(int frameSize, int[] data)
        {
            int padding = frameSize / 2;
            double sum = 0;
            double[] avgPoints = new double[data.Length - frameSize + 1];

            for (int counter = padding; counter <= data.Length - padding; counter++)//for (int counter = padding; counter <= data.Length - frameSize; counter++)
            {
                int innerLoopCounter = 0;
                int index = counter;
                while (innerLoopCounter < frameSize)
                {
                   // if (index < data.Length)
                    sum = sum + data[index];

                    innerLoopCounter += 1;

                    index += 1;

                }

                avgPoints[counter] = sum / frameSize;

                sum = 0;

            }

            return avgPoints;

        }
```

Comment: Are you simply asking how to make the X-axis start from a non-zero index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure:

`for (int counter = padding; counter <= data.Length - frameSize; counter++)`

shouldn't be:

`for (int counter = padding; counter <= data.Length - padding; counter++)`

And then your function that computes the moving average should go from counter - padding to counter + padding instead of from counter to counter + frameSize.

To debug this type of problem, it's often helpful to try it which a much smaller data set where you can compute the expected result by hand and see if your algorithm matches your expectations.  I don't believe that your algorithm is necessarily calculating what you think it's calculating here.  Try it with 10 data elements and a window size of 3 to see if you're getting the results that you expect.

*Note, the first code line actually contains 2 logic errors, one of which is not necessarily apparent until you try the code 2nd line.  The error is preserved for illustrative purposes*

Comment: Pete Baughman i tried it. Im getting exception on the line: sum = sum + data[index]; the exception is: Index was outside the bounds of the array. the variable sum = 33215.0 data = 2255 and index = 2255 and thats when frameSize is 300 in the beginning and data is 2255.

Comment: Pete the error is show up only after changed the line as you suggested above.

Comment: Alright, let's read the exception and figure out what it's telling us.  It sounds like you're trying to access data beyond the bounds of your array.  If your array contains 2255 elements, then the highest your index can go is 2254 because indexes start counting at 0 (consider the case where the array contains a single item.   How high can you go then?)  If index is 2255 then you are indeed trying to access an element that isn't there.  You should ask yourself:  Why is the code trying to access this element?  It likely has to do with the range check of "counter" in your 'for' loop

Comment: Pete i got it. Then what should i do to fix it ? Tried now in For loop to make counter = padding - 1 but that is not the solution. Could you show me please what to do in my code ?

Comment: You're close, but the issue isn't where the for loop starts, it's where the for loop ends.  Most for loops, when indexing an array look like: for(index = 0; index < arrayLength; index += 1).  Your for loop uses less-than-or-equals instead of less-than

Comment: Pete i did it like this: if (index < data.Length)
                    sum = sum + data[index]; i just added an if check. Is that look logical and also look logical by the result ? I looked at the graph now and it seems looks like i wanted to be.

Comment: That's going to be difficult for someone to maintain in the future because they're going to have to dig through the for loop and discover that it doesn't actually do anything for one iteration.  It would be much better to fix the range of index directly.

Comment: I just updated my question added the new function as i changed but getting the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible* Some languages, like pascal allow this, but not c#.

Why not just subtract the offset 150:

```
sum += data[index - 150];
```

*although not possible with an array, you can achieve the effect with a custom object that implements an indexed property.

```
private int[] _array;

public int this[int index]
{
  get{ return _array[index - 150]; }
}
```